# Must we call getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this) after setListAdapter(adapter)?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I just noticed that every example that I have seen uses `ListFragment` and calls

```
adapter = new Adapter(context);
setListAdapter(adapter);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

exactly in that order.

When I use `Fragment`, and do this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new Adapter(mContext);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

it doesn't work. I traced inside `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)` and noticed that the `adapter` doesn't know its `ListView`, so the `swapCursor(newCursor)` doesn't have an effect.

But when I do this, it works.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new Adapter(mContext);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    return view;
}
```

I feel like I know the problem, but I need an explanation to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adapter.swapCursor()` has no effect because you never set the adapter to the ListView after the adapter was initialized.

`onCreateView()` is called before `onActivityCreated()`. When you are setting the adapter to the ListView inside `onCreateView()` it is probably null. Then in `onActivityCreated()` you initialize the adapter but is not related to the listview.

Comment: "onCreateView() is called before onActivityCreated()" duh! I just remembered this. okay..